# Composition of token-glueing macros

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I got these macros

```
#define NEXT(of_) ((of_ ## _SUFFIX) + 1)
#define AA_SUFFIX (1)
#define BB_SUFFIX (NEXT(AA))  // expands to ((((1)) + 1))
#define CC_SUFFIX (NEXT(BB))  // expands to ((((NEXT(AA))) + 1)) !!!
```

I want CC_SUFFIX to expand to 3, but it doesn't (see above).
Is there a way to make the preprocessor evaluate NEXT(AA) in this case?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15432585/519383) answer, the preprocessor *"[...] recursively expands the replacement text for occurences of other macros (the macro itself is blocked in these recursive calls.)"*.

Taking this into account it makes sense that the expansion for `CC_SUFFIX` ends up being `((((NEXT(AA))) + 1))` since the macro `NEXT(of_)` was already used once. To confirm that this is the cause you can create a new macro that does the same thing as `NEXT(of_)` and use it in `BB_SUFFIX`:

```
#define NEXT(of_) ((of_ ## _SUFFIX) + 1)
#define NEXT1(of_) ((of_ ## _SUFFIX) + 1)
#define AA_SUFFIX (1)
#define BB_SUFFIX (NEXT1(AA))
#define CC_SUFFIX (NEXT(BB))

int main(void){
  BB_SUFFIX;
  CC_SUFFIX;
}
```

Running `gcc -E macros.c` the output is:

```
# 1 "/home/jfacorro/dev/macros-expand.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/home/jfacorro/dev/macros-expand.c"
int main(void){
  ((((1)) + 1));
  (((((((1)) + 1))) + 1));
}
```

As a side note, there's no need to wrap the macro's expression in parenthesis, if you lose them, the expansion would read a lot cleaner.

```
#define NEXT(of_) of_ ## _SUFFIX + 1
#define NEXT1(of_) of_ ## _SUFFIX + 1
#define AA_SUFFIX 1
#define BB_SUFFIX NEXT1(AA)
#define CC_SUFFIX NEXT(BB)
```

Produce the output:

```
int main(void){
  1 + 1;
  1 + 1 + 1;
}
```